# Dell Precision Hibernation support

Tags: 16.04, dell, hibernate

I am researching Hibernation support for Dell Preceision laptops.  I have found several pages suggesting the models I am researching have been certified with Ubuntu.

Would this certification process include testing with Hibernation?